# Can someone solve this error , it occurs every I click the Icon

Tags: flutter, error-handling

```dart
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor:
          width > webScreenSize ? webBackgroundColor : Colors.white,
      appBar: width > webScreenSize
          ? null
          : AppBar(
              backgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
              centerTitle: false,
              title: SvgPicture.network(
                '',
                color: primaryColor,
                height: 40,
              ),
              actions: [
                  Center(
                    child: Row(children: [
                      IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.add_box_outlined,
                          color: primaryColor,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const AddPostScreen(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
                  ),
                ]),
```

[This is the error that shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNQ9p.png)

Comment: Try wrapping `AddPostScreen` with `Material` widget.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your `Widget` with `MaterialApp`.